# Array Searching

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

So say I have the following array:

```
array(
    'key1'=>array(
        'key.1'=>'tester',
        'key.2'=>'tester'
    ),
    'key2'=>array(
        'key.1'=>'failedtester',
        'key.2'=>'tester'
    )
)
```

How do I search this array such that I return back the parent keys such that a value is a certain value based off a sub key?
e.g. Return the keys such that key.1 == tester (this would return key1)
e.g. Return the keys such that key.1 == failedtester (this would return key2)
e.g. Return the keys such that key.2 == tester (this would return array(key1, key2)

Is this possible without doing a for loop?


Edit: Using PHP (sorry thought I had said PHP, apparently not.. #fail)

Comment: What language? Or is it really language-agnostic?

Comment: Guess you're using PHP? You really should tell us what language you're using ...

Comment: @xanatos based on user's tags, looks like [tag:php]

Comment: @all Thanks, I imagined... But I don't add language tags "blindly" :-)

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought I had added it, but apparently not. Thanks for adding it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:** two nested loops, total time complexity is O(n*n):

```
function search1($a, $key, $val) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($a as $a_key => $a_arr) {
       foreach ($a_arr as $k => $v) {
           if ($k == $key && $v == $val) {
               $result[] = $a_key;
           }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$result = search1($a, "key.1", "tester"); // call
```

**Solution 2:** the inner loop is replaced by a lookup, total complexity is O(n*log(n)). This should be significantly faster for large n:

```
function search2($a, $key, $val) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($a as $a_key => $a_arr) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $a_arr) && $a_arr[$key] == $val) {
               $result[] = $a_key;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$result = search2($a, "key.1", "tester"); // call
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:**

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['key.1'] == 'tester') $results[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't use lopping.

Comment: @Aram Papazian, One way or another, a loop is going to be involved.  There is no built-in PHP function for what you want and any function that does what you want is going to using a loop.

Comment: @simshaun That works then. I was just trying to figure out if there was a way to do it without looping or not. If not, then that works. (I already had created a loop version, but was trying to find a more efficient version without looping.) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could use a hash table.  Each location of the hash would be a linked list of keys that hashed to that term.  This would run your searches in constant time too!

Comment: Is the data presorted in the array?
do you have to use a standard multidimensional array to store the data, or can you use a different data structure?